# What is the array form of 'delete'?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

When I compiled a code using the array name as a pointer, and I deleted the array name using `delete`, I got a warning about deleting an array without using the array form (I don't remember the exact wording).

The basic code was:

```
int data[5];
delete data;
```

So, what's the array form of delete?

Comment: That invokes undefined behavior because the array was not allocated with new[].

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The array form of delete is:

```
delete [] data;
```

**Edit:** But as others have pointed out, you shouldn't be calling `delete` for data defined like this:

```
int data[5];
```

You should only call it when you allocate the memory using `new` like this:

```
int *data = new int[5];
```

Comment: But his int data[5] was not allocated by operator new(), so there is no correct form of operator delete() that can be called.

Comment: Interesting... the answer is correct, but oh so wrong. How did he get 17 votes already?

Comment: It is so easy to answer the question actually asked, instead of the question that should have been asked. Especially when its repeated both in the title and as the last sentence.

Comment: Jared - confining myself only to your question, and not the question of whether this answer is worthy or not, perhaps it's the case that answers marked as the accepted answer tend to attract more votes. It'd be interesting to see if the SO folks do any statistical analysis on the rates of voting for all answers before and after one is marked accepted.

Comment: So in the original question, if the user does not call the form of delete mentioned above and does not create the data in the alternative form, will he or she create a memory leak? UPDATE: No it won't.

Answer (score 22):

You either want:

```
int *data = new int[5];
... // time passes, stuff happens to data[]
delete[] data;
```

or

```
int data[5];
... // time passes, stuff happens to data[]
// note no delete of data
```

The genera rule is: only apply `delete` to memory that came from `new`. If the array form of `new` was used, then you *must* use the array form of `delete` to match. If placement `new` was used, then you either never call `delete` at all, or use a matching placement `delete`.

Since the variable `int data[5]` is a statically allocated array, it cannot be passed to any form of the `delete` operator.

Answer (score 5):

As the other have said, you must use the vector form of delete:

```
void some_func(size_t n)
{
  int* data = new int[n];

  . . . // do stuff with the array

  delete [] data; // Explicitly free memory
}
```

Be very wary of this, because some compilers will *not* warn you.

Even better, there is very rarely any need for using vector new/delete. Consider whether your code can be altered to make use of std::vector:

```
void some_func(size_t n)
{
  std::vector<int> data(n);

  . . . // do stuff with the array

} // memory held by data will be freed here automatically
```

And if you are dealing with the memory in a local scope, consider using [STLSoft](http://stlsoft.org/)'s [auto_buffer](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/classstlsoft_1_1auto__buffer.html), which will allocate from an internal buffer (held on the stack, as part of the instance) if possible, only going to the heap if it cannot:

```
void some_func(size_t n)
{
  stlsoft::auto_buffer<int, 10> data(n); // only allocates if n > 10

  . . . // do stuff with the array

} // memory held by data will be freed here automatically, if any was allocated
```

Read [more about auto_buffer](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401740).

Answer (score 2):

The code as shown has the array either on the stack, or in initialized part of the data segment, i.e. you don't deallocate it (which, as mentioned by others, would be "undefined behavior".) Were it on the "free store", you'd do that with `delete [] data`.

Answer (score 0):

Just as RichieHindle stated above when you want to free the space dynamically allocated for an array pointed by `data` you have to put two brackets `[]` between the reserved word `delete` and the pointer to the beginning of the allocated space. Since `data` can point to a single `int` in memory as well as to the first element in the array this is the only way you let the compiler know that you want to delete the whole chunk of memory. If you don't do it the proper way the behaviour is "undetermined" (Stroustrup, *The C++ Programming Language*).

Answer (score 0):

Fixes C4154 and C4156 warnings

```
float AR[5] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, ..., ..., ...};

delete [] & AR;
```

Comment: This is very wrong. If the array wasn't created with `new[]` it's undefined behavior to try to `delete[]` it. If you're lucky it will crash so you can find this terrible bug.