# Delete causes unexpected crash

Tags: c++, constructor, crash, destructor

This is a simple program I wrote:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string *word = new string[1]; //create a string object

    *word = "blablabla"; //assign a string to that object

    cout << "String: " << *word << endl;

    delete word; //delete object? Causes unexected crash

    int *ar = new int [10]; //create array of 10 blocks

    ar[3] = 4; //assign a value to bl-3

    cout << ar[3] << endl;

    delete ar; //delete object, works

    return 0;
}
```

Now from what I understand so far, one uses `delete` with `new` (as in delete one object that I created) and `delete[]` with `new[]` (delete and create an array of objects). The problem is that the former `delete` causes my program to crash while the latter works fine. Doing `delete[] word` works, however.

So how am I creating an array of objects? Am I mistaken in thinking that `string *word = new string[1]` creates just one object?

Comment: You delete arrays like this `delete [] word`.

Comment: The number of objects you create does not matter.  If you use `new[]` you **must** use `delete[]`.

Comment: If you are not playing with pointer, I would suggest use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/860452/862973)

Comment: So the `delete ar` working is just a coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how am I creating an array of objects? Am I mistaken in thinking that `string *word = new string[1]` creates just one object?

Sort of.

You are creating an array of 1 object.

You are creating one object. That's true. You are still creating an array.

Hence, you need to use the `delete []` form.

```
delete [] word;
```

and

```
delete [] ar;
```

Comment: @HichigayaHachiman, that's the correct understanding. You need to use `delete [] ar;`.