# How to correctly delete 2d array with known second dimension size?

Tags: c++

My array:

```
int (*arr)[100] = new int[100][100];
```

How should I correctly delete this?

edit:
I know how delete works, but i am not sure if I should delete it like this

```
delete[] arr;
```

or like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    delete[] arr[i];
}
delete[] arr;
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the array form of 'delete'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860447/what-is-the-array-form-of-delete)

Comment: If you have to use `new`, consider making the type name easier to read by using `auto arr = new int[100][100];`

Comment: why not just just use std::vector<std::vector<int>> to achieve the same thing and no need to worry about the delete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `delete[] arr;` should do just fine.

Whether you are freeing `new int[100][100][100][100]` or `new int[100]` you use `delete[] x;`. If it's a single object, you use `delete x;`.